# Binding exchange to exchange in Symfony messenger component

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-4.4, symfony-messenger

Is it possible to define binding between exchanges in Symfony messenger component? (4.4 version here).

I know that it's possible binding exchange to the queue like here:

```yaml
transports:
            incoming:
                dsn: "%env(RABBITMQ_SHARED_URL)%"
                options:
                    queues:
                        app.pl_incoming_events:
                            binding_keys:
                                - pl.app.#
                    exchange:
                        name: my_app.incoming
                        type: topic
```

And then app setups exchange, queue and binding between them. I'd expect the same effect to bind exchange to another exchange basing on the routing key.

I know that I can use rabbitmq-bundle but IMO is redundant - I'd like to stay with one component for managing rabbitMQ.

For instance I'd like to bind `other_app` exchange to `my_app.incoming` exchange basing on some route key.

Answer (score 4):

Messenger is not a RabbitMQ manager, you cannot even declare multiple exchanges in the same transport out of the box.
But since it has all the required components and in this case symfony is a bit permissive with the config, you can abuse the system and build it yourself.

Since I don't know your requirements I'll keep it basic, hopefully it'll get you started.

Start by creating `AmqpTransportFactory`:

```
// src/Amqp/AmqpTransportFactory.php
namespace App\Amqp;

use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\AmqpExt\AmqpFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\AmqpExt\AmqpTransport;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\AmqpExt\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\Serialization\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\TransportFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\TransportInterface;

class AmqpTransportFactory implements TransportFactoryInterface
{
    public function createTransport(
        string $dsn, array $options, SerializerInterface $serializer
    ): TransportInterface
    {
        unset($options['transport_name']);
        $exchanges['name'] = $options['exchange']['name'];
        $exchanges['bindings'] = $options['exchange']['bindings'] ?? [];

        // Passing unknown options is deprecated in 5.1
        unset($options['exchange']['bindings']);

        $connection = Connection::fromDsn($dsn, $options);

        // Ensure our exchange is created first
        $connection->exchange()->declareExchange();
        $channel = $connection->channel();
    
        // This is normally done in the Connection, but is harder to override
        $this->createExchanges($channel, $exchanges);

        return new AmqpTransport($connection, $serializer);
    }

    public function supports(string $dsn, array $options): bool
    {
        return 0 === strpos($dsn, 'amqp://');
    }

    private function createExchanges(\AMQPChannel $channel, array $configuration): void
    {
        $factory = new AmqpFactory();

        foreach ($configuration['bindings'] as $exchange_name => $arguments) {
            $exchange = $factory->createExchange($channel);
            $exchange->setName($exchange_name);
            $exchange->setType($arguments['type'] ?? \AMQP_EX_TYPE_FANOUT);
            $exchange->setFlags($arguments['flags'] ?? \AMQP_DURABLE);
            $exchange->declareExchange();

            if (!is_array($arguments['binding_keys'])) {
                $arguments['binding_keys'] = [$arguments['binding_keys']];
            }

            foreach ($arguments['binding_keys'] as $key) {
                $exchange->bind($configuration['name'], $key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register the service:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
  messenger.transport.amqp.factory:
    class: App\Amqp\AmqpTransportFactory
```

Add the new configuration to the exchange:

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
exchange:
  name: my_app.incoming
  type: topic
  bindings:
    other_app:
      type: direct
      binding_keys: ['route']
```

And it will result on the following bindings:

```
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|     source      |      destination       |      routing_key       |
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| my_app.incoming | app.pl_incoming_events | pl.app.#               |
| my_app.incoming | other_app              | route                  |
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply! But I'm not sure if it's a good place for setup - messenger assumes that Connection class is responsible for that (see `setupExchangeAndQueues` in `\Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\AmqpExt\Connection`). In other scenarios  it will use `setupExchangeAndQueues` method (it's executed 5 in 5 places in Connection class) from the mentioned class and still there will be wrong setup of exchanges. I'm asking if it's possible using built-in features but as I looking in the code it seems to be impossible (and you confirmed that).

Comment: Yes, I'm perfectly aware, also that that method is private. There's a comment in the code when I point it out, you are welcome to override Connection directly, but as a SO answer that's the general idea. However, as the first couple of sentences say "it's not a manager, cannot even declare multiples exchanges in a transport" so "using builtin features" would be a hard no. But I don't see why would be wrong setup of exchanges. I'm declaring "our" exchange explicitly to ensure it's defined. You can call `setup()` on Connection if that gives you more confidence.